# Control Google Home devices with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: pi-pico, google-nest

I have a pile of buttons and raspberry pi pico’s (I went a bit overboard when they went on sale), and wish to connect them to Google Home to control my devices.

Basically, I want each button to do a specific thing (Such as pressing button one will turn on device A, and pressing button two will turn it off) or for each button to control one device (So button one will simply change that status of Device A), whichever is easier.

I have searched the internet, but I have only found one instructable, and it focuses on the Raspberry Pi 3, and controlling Google with your voice, not a button.

At this point, I don't have any code, I just wish to know if this is even possible in the first place, and if it is, what directions would I need to follow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah let me see.  (1) If you know how to use Pico microPython to read a button and blink a LED, then you are OK to start the project. (2) For big current devices, you need a relay. (3) For newbie friendly tutorials, I recommend Tom's Hardware: https://www.tomshardware.com/search?searchTerm=pico

Comment: Of course, you'll need to figure out how google home will be able to "connect" to these Pico's

Comment: @Bravo, that is really the part I am stuck on. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A more appropriate place to research that would be our larger parent site, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).   But before you post there, keep in mind that people do not always react kindly to questions that scream, "I have done exactly zero research on this topic because I am hoping somebody else can use their time (rather than me wasting mine) to write me a simple introduction..." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-home

Comment: WRT "Can I do this with a Pi Pico?" the answer is yes *if it has a way to communicate onliine*, which obviously requires some extra hardware and may mean it is not an appropriate device for your purpose.

Comment: option 1: USB to serial. Option 2: serial -> wifi chip connected to Pico (i.e. ESP8266/32)